# Default font size and line height for the page

Tags: html, css

Is it better to start my site with a `html,body{font-size: 100%; line-height: 1rem;}`

Or Is is better to start my site with no font size and no line height;

What is the best way to start.

If I inspect the code on many different sites I see everyone does it differently.

My preference has always been to start with `font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2px;`
and then set all my fonts in px after that. That way fonts will always be rendered at the size I want.

Comment: Try Sizing With rem. Here is a link for reference https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: Can you be more specific please. Does that mean leaving out  a default size on the html,body?

Comment: set the font-size to percentage on html, body. on all other elements you make use of rem units..

Answer (score 0):

I also had same kind of question sometime back. below link helped me to understand clearly.

**Percent (%):** The percent unit is much like the “em” unit, save for a few fundamental differences. First and foremost, the current font-size is equal to 100% (i.e. 12pt = 100%). While using the percent unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for accessibility.

https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Thanks , I'll have a look